# undefined symbols _Z7_getcwdPci when linking c++ and fortran source code

Tags: c++, fortran, undefined, symbols, ld

I'm trying to port a program written in Microsoft Visual Studio (in c, c++ and fortran) to a mac OSX. Within this program is a c++ function being called by a fortran source code. Basically its interloping c++ and fortran. I have wrapped the C++ function in an `"extern C"` brackets, which I'm told via the internet is the proper method. However, the linker is still complaining of an undefined symbol within this c++ function...

> ```
> Undefined symbols:
>   "__Z7_getcwdPci", referenced from:
>       _bisimr_ in bisimR.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found
> ```

if you look through the internet, `getcwd` is a function defined in a header file, `"direct.h"`. It is not part of the mac OS and is only inherent on a Windows system. I was able to find the file on the internet that, to the best of my knowledge, seems to be the windows "direct.h" file.

Now that we are done with the context, here is my question

Given that I get an error, could it be that my `direct.h` file is not the correct header file that is part of Windows? or is name mangling, going from C++ to fortran, throwing out this error?

note:

- I can get through the compile stage, its the linking of the libraries that throws this error.
- `bisimr_` is the c++ function

Comment: According to the POSIX standard, `getcwd` should be in `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: oh i forgot to mention that im using  ifort, gcc and g++ as my compilers

Comment: i tried using unistd.h , it gave me the same error along with loads of other undefined references

Comment: Wait a minute, did you just try to put a Windows header in the source and include that? That won't work.

Comment: can you elaborate by what you mean larsmans? and yes i grabbed the header file off the internet, and wrote "#include "direct.h" " into the source code

Comment: You can't just put a header for a different OS in your source code. You'll have the function declarations, but not the definitions; those live in the runtime libraries for the OS in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you tried to build the program by *copying* a header file from a *Windows* system. Right so far? That approach is bound to fail: the presence of the header file will provide the *compiler* with information as to what functions are available on a *Windows* system, but the *linker* will complain because none of the listed libraries defines a function of said name.

You should only be using headers which come with your system, or from third-party libraries which you already compiled successfully for your system. Sourcecode-only headers (template libraries in particular) are OK as well. The use of any other header is just asking for linker errors.

The fact that the name appears mangled is an indication that the compiler considers it a C++ function which might be overloaded, so it will include details about the argument types in the name. That aspect might be avoided by enclosing the `#include` statement in an `extern "C"` block. For the windows file `direct.h` this will not solve the above problems, but perhaps it will make `unistd.h` useful to you:

```
extern "C" {
#include <unistd.h>
}
```

Comment: it worked! i followed MvG's instructions and the linker is not complaining anymore. thanks ! you guys are awesome

Comment: In that case, you should upvote and accept the answer which worked for you.

Comment: Accepting should be enough.  New users even  do not have the priviliges to upvote and downvote.